# Attempted import error: 'createNote' is not exported from './graphql/mutations' (imported as 'createNoteMutation')

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services

I am following the Amazon AWS free tier course and have an issue with [module 4](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-four/), "Add API and database."

The code that i am trying to run in `src/App.js` was obtained from that link. The error is: `Attempted import error: 'createNote' is not exported from './graphql/mutations' (imported as 'createNoteMutation')`

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me is with the name:

- `createNote` is `createTodo`
- `deleteNote` is `deleteTodo`

The code in `mutations.js` is:

```
export const createTodo = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreateTodo(
    $input: CreateTodoInput!
    $condition: ModelTodoConditionInput
  ) {
    createTodo(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      name
      description
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

Change the names and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I looked in the import folder and it turns out for some reason that the proper GraphQL functions weren't there. So, updating the GraphQL API fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also the import of `listNotes` from the graphql queries is having this issue.

I fixed as below:

```
import { listTodos as listNotes } from './graphql/queries';
```

The issue from this question was fixed as below;

```
import { createTodo as createNoteMutation, deleteTodo as deleteNoteMutation } from './graphql/mutations';
```

Comment: did you manually create './graphql/queries' ?

Answer (score 0):

The last answer by Dan worked for me.

For the noobs like me out there,

1. src/app.js is the file to change.
2. insert the code syntax below per Dans solution...
   [copy the below in at about line 14-15]
   *import { listTodos as listNotes } from './graphql/queries';
   import { createTodo as createNoteMutation, deleteTodo as deleteNoteMutation } from './graphql/mutations';*
   [end of copy]

Should now compile, and allow you to test [the Step 4.4 of the AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-four/) tutorial. (You'd think the tutorial writers would test this before releasing it, right..?)

Comment: These answers are helpful, but as a real noob, I still cannot find whether I am to make './graphql/mutations.js' file or whether I do something in the console and pull it into my project, this stage of all learning material is missing a lot of information, a lot has to be assumed. Can you help?